# 815A Micronas HAL sensor programming

Tags: hall-effect

I am trying to program an 815A HAL sensor made by Micronas. I read the datasheet and made the following bitbang to read a register value.

No success!

Has anybody here worked with this sensor?

[image]

Comment: Is it a new sensor, or a used one?  The 815A can be "locked" so that it can't be adjusted any more.  A locked IC won't answer commands.

Comment: I've bought them as new chip. I'm not sure about the lock bit. it seems the chip sends the ack bit after my read command so doesn't this indicate anything about the lock bit?

Comment: btw if you have worked with chips is the bit-bang correct? Do you have any sample code to share with me?

Comment: I have never used one.  I just had a look at the datasheet.

Comment: based on the datasheet can you please confirm I'm doing it correctly? I need someone to verify my understanding of the datasheet.

Comment: What command did you try to send?

Comment: It supposed to be a read command for address 01.

Comment: Sorry any comments ?